# Getting hidden input value to a jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, jquery-selectors, ognl

I am using a struts 2 `<s:iterator>` tag to add data to a jsp page. It is basically like this.

```
<s:iterator value="applicants" var="applicant">
   <label>Applicant Name</label>
   <s:property value="#applicant.firstName"/>
   <s:property value="#applicant.lastName"/>

   <button class="btn btn-success">Approve</button>
   <s:hidden class="applicantid" value="%{#applicant.id}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

How can I get the relevant applicant id to a variable in jquery when I click the approve button? I tried closest(), siblings() methods but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use the class `applicatid` as selector

Answer (score 2):

You are using `class` instead of `cssClass` that doesn't exist. Some Struts2 tags **allow dynamic attributes**, and hence on some of them, putting `class` will work, on others more strict, it will raise a parsing error. Always use `cssClass` and `cssStyle` in Struts tags.

That said, your solution

> ```javascript
> var hidden_value = $(this).closest('div').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
> ```

is relying on the html generated by the Struts2 theme, that might change if you change theme for the project, the form, the element, or even by upgrading the Struts library. You should instead use the appropriate selector, in this case the class one:

```javascript
var hidden_value = $(".applicantid").val();
```

This will apply to every element with that class, however.

If you need to apply it to a single element (the one aside the button pressed) just generate an unique `id` for every hidden element and use the id selector, like:

```xml
<s:iterator value="applicants" var="applicant" status="ctr">
   ...
   <s:hidden id="applicantid_%{#ctr.index}" 
       cssClass="applicantid" 
          value="%{#applicant.id}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

and

```javascript
var hidden_value = $("#applicantid_1").val();
```

Where the unique number is retrieved somewhere, for example generated basing on the iteration also in the button's id (like `button_1`), extracted with javascript and used to mount the hidden id (`applicantid_1`).

Comment: Just fyi - since ~2.3.20 https://github.com/apache/struts/commit/6fbd1bef3a91eb6992507086b75f6d22bcb95fb2.

Comment: Let me guess, class and style ?

Comment: Yep, :) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4166, https://github.com/apache/struts/commit/6fbd1bef3a91eb6992507086b75f6d22bcb95fb2

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    var hidden_value = $('.applicantid').val();
    console.log(hidden_value);
}
```

This is using the class btn from the button and the on click event of it to assign the value of the hidden field to the hidden_value variable, using applicantid class as selector.

Comment: Tried it and it print unassigned. Then i tried directly printing value to html using <s:property value="%{#applicant.id}"/> and correct id appears

Comment: I think you should assign ids to the elements and use those instead of the classes, it will be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to do it using this

```
var hidden_value = $(this).closest('div').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
```